# jQuery toggle this text

Tags: jquery, text, replace

I've done some research and found solutions, but I'd like to keep this simple and allow for dynamic text.

I have various links that have text that says something:

```
<a>Unique Link 1</a>
<a>Unique Link 2</a>
<a>Unique Link 3</a>
```

But, when you click on these links—I want to toggle the text 'Link #' with 'Close' and then toggle back to whatever the original is once you click on the link again.

Currently I'm doing this inside of a click function:

```
jQuery(this).text('Close');
if (jQuery(this).text('Close')) {
    jQuery('a.expand').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).text('///Original Dynamic Text Here///');
    });
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery: replace text and reset on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291320/jquery-replace-text-and-reset-on-click)

Comment: You can store the original text value as a data attribute

Answer (score 0):

Put ids on your `a` tags then

```
var texts = {};//Will hold your dynamic texts
jQuery("a").on("click",function(){
    var jt = jQuery(this);
    if(jt.text()!=="Close"){
        texts[jt.attr("id")] = jt.text();//Save dynamic text to object
        jt.text("Close");
    }else{
         jt.text(texts[jt.attr("id")]);//Get dynamic text back
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!